# Multiple tkafkainfputs in Talend

Tags: talend

I want to create a flow with 4 `tkafkainputs` in order to raise 4 consumers but when I connect each of them with `onComponentok` with `tkafkaconnection` only one is created when the job runs.

How can I achieve that?

[image: Flow]

UPDATE:
I have tried `tparallelize` but it didn't work. After few seconds the job ends despite the fact that `tkafkainputs` are configured to stay open for 50 minutes. Also I tried  `tparallelize` and 4 `trunjobs` but the same thing like above happened.

Comment: Did you try to use tparallelize component  if you are working on talend entreprise ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa adding the tparallelize after the tkafkaconnection ?

Comment: yes ! then delete all onComponentok and match with parallezation  tkafkaconnection-->OncomponentOK --> tparallelize --> tkafkainput1

Comment: or use onsubjobOk other of oncomponentOk !

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa it didint work with onsubjobok

Comment: Are you committing correctly to add values in your DBOutput (using autocommit ) or try to put some logs in output to see what is going wrong

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa It worked for a while but after some time it stopped. Maybe it is the wait for configuration or sleep duration in tparallelize.  I want the job to run for one hour.

Comment: Yes probebly , try to configure that  till it work with what you are attending .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233745/discussion-between-drgenius-and-amine-ben-khelifa).

Comment: An update about this topic ? if parralel execution helped , kindly mark topic as solved

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa It doesnt. It raises 4 consumers as I want but it ends the job after few seconds despite the fact that the tkafkainputs are configured to be open for 50 mins

Comment: You will have probebly to update your question and add your second issue and develop the issue so that we can help

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use parallel execution using component tParallelize other of using OnComponentOk  link .

This wil help you execute your subjob on parallel so that your consumers  would be created .

This is the officiel documentation : https://help.talend.com/r/AA9xpk1ns2gYIzJwDT4ESw/VPlms8ge2xze78vP6eVvVQ .